# Why does bool exist when we can use int?

Tags: c++, boolean

This may sound as a really dumb question. But it has been bothering me for the past few days. And It's not only concerning the C++ Programming Language as I've added it's tag. My Question is that. In **Computer Science** Boolean (bool) datatype has only two possible values. 'true' or 'false'. And also, in Computer Science, 1 is true and 0 is false. So why does boolean exists at all? Why not we use an integer that can return only two possible values, Such as 1 or 0.

For example :

```cpp
bool mindExplosion = true; // true!
int mindExplosion = 1; // true!!
// or we can '#define true 1' and it's the same right?
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Practical considerations aside, if I am reading someone's code and see a `bool` variable declared, that tells me right off the bat that they expect it to only have two possible values.  If they declare it as an `int` instead, now I will have to dig into the code a bit before I realize that they are (mis)using that variable as a sort-of-boolean.  Having code that says was it does and does only what it says saves other programmers a fair amount of time :)

Comment: One could also ask "Why do we have `char` type if we have int?`.  After all, the character encodings are numbers.

Comment: You can count on `false` being 0.  On the other hand, `true` is `not false`, whatever that means in integers.  For example is -1 true?  Is 5 true?  So, if you are expecting a `1` as true, but the integer is 5, is the expression true?

Comment: Curiosity suppressed. I understand now.

Comment: FYI, `bool` didn't always exist!  Back in the old days, people actually did use integers for booleans.  `bool` was added later, and it just makes things easier.

Comment: Thanks for that FYI. @RemyLebeau It sure as heck makes things a lot easier.

Comment: I think all this discussion of intent also points towards a more important piece of advice: the most important audience for the code you write is other people, not the compiler. The compiler will cope with all sorts of confusing nonsense and is often clever enough to optimise the minutiae better than you can, but you can write code your colleagues (and yourself in a few months time) can understand the intent and functionality of.

Comment: If ‘bool‘ was not part of std by 2011,  I would propose against wasting a keyword for it. One can implement it in terms enums: ’enum boolean:char{b_false, b_true};’ Boolean operators could also be overloaded on it.

Comment: You're thinking about programming languages as what needs to be, instead of just along the lines of accepting what is.  You don't -- need -- boolean types.  You don't even really -- need -- integer types, could do everything with strings.

You have the computers architecture and the corresponding assembly languages that correspond to its opcodes.  Everything else just is, and may or may not correspond to certain underlying functionality. 

If you just learn caveats about when bool vs ints are treated different (eg you can use either as unique template arguments), that's the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does bool exist when we can use int?

Well, you don't need something as large as an `int` to represent two states so it makes sense to allow for a smaller type to save space

> Why not we use an integer that can return only two possible values, Such as 1 or 0.

That is exactly what `bool` is.  [It is an unsigned integer type that represents true (1) or false (0).](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.fundamental#10)

---

Another nice thing about having a specific type for this is that it express intent without any need for documentation.  If we had a function like (warning, very contrived example)

```
void output(T const & val, bool log)
```

It is easy to see that log is an option and if we pass false it wont log.  If it were instead

```
void output(T const & val, int log)
```

Then we aren't sure what it does.  Is it asking for a log level?  A flag on whether to log or not? Something else?

Answer (score 6):

> What am I missing?

Expressiveness.

When a variable is declared `int` it might be *used* only for 0 and 1, or it might hold anything from `INT_MIN..INT_MAX`.

When a variable is declared `bool`, it is made *explicit* that it is to hold a true / false value.

Among other things, this allows the compiler to toss warnings when an `int` is used in places where you really want a `bool`, or attempt to store a `2` in a `bool`. The compiler is your friend; give it all the hints possible so it can tell you when your code starts looking funky.